# Ordering one list using another list by using an intermediate dictionary loses items in the result

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

There are two lists as follows:

```
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Bob"]
heights = [155, 185, 150]
```

`names[i]`'s height is `heights[i]`, where `i=0,1,2`. I want to order `names` using their height from high to low. That said the output should be `["Bob", "Alice", "Bob"]`.

Below is the code I wrote:

```
temp = dict(zip(names, heights))
sort_temp = sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
res = []
for i in sort_temp:
    res.append(i[0])
print(res)
```

Below is the result:

```
["Alice", "Bob"]
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a dictionary using the names as key. But a dictionary cannot have each key more than once, therefore the second `"Bob"` (with height 150) overwrites the existing `"Bob"` (with height 185).

It's not clear why you create a dictionary at all. Just create a list of tuples directly:

Change `dict(...)` to `list(...)` and omit `.items()`.

---

It would also be simpler if you made tuples (height, name) instead of (name, height), then you could omit `key=...`, since tuples are sorted by their first item already (using the second item to resolve a tie). Then you would have to adjust `i[0]` to `i[1]`.

Once you have done this sort of operation enough times you will notice that you can write the whole code as

```
res = [name for height, name in sorted(zip(heights, names), reverse=True)]
```